# How many services can I host with Topshelf?

Tags: topshelf

[Topshelf docs](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html) say:

> You can only have ONE service! As of 3.x Topshelf the base product no
>   longer support hosting multiple services. This was done because the
>   code to implement was very brittle and hard to debug. We have opted
>   for a simpler and cleaner base product. This feature will most likely
>   come back in the form of an add on nuget.

But this works for v.4  We can host multiple services. Are we doing something potentially wrong or are docs just stale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many Topshelf host services running on a box as you want, but you used to be able to host multiple logical services (e.g. `x.Service<MyService1>(...); x.Service<MyService2>(...);`) within a single Topshelf host.

You can even run multiple instances of the same Topshelf host service multiple times using the instance parameter.

Comment: Yes, exactly how you describe, x.Service<MyServiceN>(...)

Comment: I was a bit to quick with marking this as an answer. Could you clarify, please:  "but you used to be able to host multiple logical services" Does this mean it doesn't work anymore? But how then should I understand this phrase: "You can have as many Topshelf host services running on a box as you want" ?

Comment: @PavelVoronin I am also looking for answer!